# Implying a boolean function by using 5 NANDS only - How to implant "1" using nand?

Tags: digital-logic, boolean-algebra, karnaugh-map

Function:
f(a,b,c,d) = b' + c' + ad + a'd'
I used Karnaugh map (4x4).
Received that the function is all squares except square number 7 (there it is 0).
Which means:

[image]

Now what is the problem? When I do the reduction I receive:
f(a,b,c,d) = **a' + cd' + a + a'b'** ### a + ab = a(1+b)
which equals to: **cd' + a'(b'+1) + a** ### (x + 1 = 1)
which equals to: **cd' + a' + a** ### (a + a' = 1 )
which equals to finally: **cd' + 1**
Now, how do I imply 1 with NANDs? Its really weird...

Comment: Isn't the answer just (ABCD)'  (or: \$\overline{ABCD}\$)?

Comment: Are you sure your Karnaugh (not "karnho") map is correct?

Comment: @ErikR no, the 0 are pos, which should be (A + B + C +D)' on all of them, but I did karhno map with sop

Comment: @Hearth Yea, I double checked it to make sure, I solved it twice, used two sheets to double check, I dont think there is any mistake

Comment: I can take picture it here if someone doesnt believe, I have no reason to lie, since karhno map is pretty easy to do, this one especially.

Comment: @Hearth and sorry for my laungage, my english is not at its best :\

Comment: The Karnaugh map you've shown here doesn't correspond to the function you said. It corresponds to a' + c' + cd' + ab', but you're talking about the function b' + c' + ad + a'd'.

Comment: @Hearth Weird, I will triple check it now :\

Comment: @Hearth Oh yea, The original function is what I wrote above. the second function ( what you wrote ) I Wrote up there

Comment: @BenShaines Sorry, I'm having trouble understanding that sentence. Are you talking about two separate functions? Why does the Karnaugh map not correspond to any of the several functions mentioned in the text?

Comment: Just one minute, I Will solve it again, I want to see why the person at the comments receive it, I am doing the map again.

Comment: @Hearth OMG I am so stupid.. I didnt notice, at ad part, I accidently toke 14 too, although d is 1 and not 0... Twice it happened to me... Thanks, the problem solved now :)

Comment: @Hearth but actually, just a question, is it possible to get 1 in nands? just curiosity, although my question does not has this problem anymore

Comment: @BenShaines You don't need any gates to get the function f(a,b,c,d) = 1. Just tie the output to the supply voltage. If you must use a gate, take a NAND gate and tie one or both inputs to ground.

Comment: The only time you need a 1 in a NAND network is if the function always outputs 1 for all possible inputs.

Comment: Allright, Thank you guys. Again, sorry for the misunderstanding here, didnt notice my mistake :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I get for f(a,b,c,d) = b' + c' + ad + a'd':

```
            AB
      00 | 01 | 11 | 10
     ------------------
   00  1    1    1    1
CD   ------------------
   01  1    1    1    1
     ------------------
   11  1    0    1    1
     ------------------
   10  1    1    0    1
     ------------------
```

Comment: Please do it with AB down and CD above, I did it that way.
I will check it now again ( what I did )

Comment: OMG I am an idiot, I accidenly toke twice the number 14. Really sorry!!